# Add TestIdentity / LegaIdentity to StartedMockNode

Tags: java, corda

How do I add additional legal identities or Party to net.corda.testing.node.StartedMockNode?

When a StartedMockNode is initiated...

```
StartedMockNode nodeC = network.createPartyNode(null);
```

... one LegalIdentiy mock is created.

That identity is then used in many of the example when creating unit tests for flows.

How do you add to that list of mocked legal identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many `StartedMockNode` as you need in your tests. This mock node is a single identity that will drive your unit tests. You cannot assign multiple identities to a single mock node, as it is not logically possible in Corda.

If you want to create multiple accounts hosted by a single mock node, you need to create a flow, say, `val account = nodeD.CreateAccount(String accountName)` that will be called by your mock node and it will create an account to be used further in your tests.

In addition, you can also assign a specific identity to the mock nodes:

```
StartedMockNode nodeD = network.createPartyNode(CordaX500Name("Alice", "London", "GB"))
```

You can also create an identity that contains a `CordaX500Name` and a `KeyPair`, alongside a range of utility methods for use during testing (API is [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/943cf0b32f13ef0dd3dfbf13e9653af8039ed590/testing/core-test-utils/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/testing/core/TestUtils.kt#L128) and example of usage [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/HEAD/Accounts/supplychain/contracts/src/test/java/net/corda/samples/supplychain/contracts/ContractTests.kt#L15)):

```
TestIdentity(CordaX500Name("Alice", "", "GB"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The key will be to use an account workflow. I will walk through the Account Library documentation https://training.corda.net/libraries/accounts-lib/

Comment: Great. I suggest you to look also into these samples to see how to use the account library: (Java) https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Accounts , (Kotlin) https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Accounts